# Async Entity Framework Core Query Throws InvalidOperation Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm doing a complex async database query with Entity Framework Core which looks like this:

```cs
Schedule schedule = await db.Schedules
    .Include("Timetable.Class.Lecturers")
    .Include("Timetable.Class.AdvancedClassSections.ClassSessions.Lecturers")
    .Include("Timetable.Class.ClassSessions.Lecturers")
    .Include("Timetable.Class.AdvancedClassSections.Lecturers")
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(k => k.ScheduleId == scheduleId);
```

But I keep getting a runtime error message which says:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model item passed into the
> ViewDataDictionary is of type
> 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Emily.Models.Timetable],Emily.Controllers.TimetableController+d__21]',
> but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Emily.Models.Timetable]'.'

It seems there's a low-level operation which should cast from IEnumerable but is getting something more complex. It was working fine when it wasn't async. I have other queries like that which are running fine, but I can't seem to figure why this one throws an exception. It has nothing to do a view because this happens in a controller action.

Full Call Stack:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary.EnsureCompatible(object
> value) Line 212   C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary.ViewDataDictionary(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary
> source, object model, System.Type declaredModelType) Line 138 C#
> [Lightweight Function]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPagePropertyActivator.Activate(object
> page, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.ViewContext context) Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.IRazorPage
> page, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.ViewContext context) Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.IRazorPage
> page, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.ViewContext context, bool
> invokeViewStarts) Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.ViewContext
> context)  Unknown
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.ViewContext
> viewContext, string contentType, int? statusCode) Line 128    C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionContext
> actionContext, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.IView view,
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary viewData,
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ITempDataDictionary tempData,
> string contentType, int? statusCode) Line 104 C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionContext
> context, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult result)  C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionContext
> context) Line 33  C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IResultFilter,
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IAsyncResultFilter>(ref
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.State next,
> ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Scope
> scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Line 1338  C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IResultFilter,
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IAsyncResultFilter>() Line 1354  C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IResultFilter,
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.IAsyncResultFilter>(ref
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.State next,
> ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Scope
> scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Line 1258  C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
> Line 1090 C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.State next,
> ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Scope
> scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Line 853   C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
> Line 952  C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.State next,
> ref Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Scope
> scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted) Line 557   C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> Line 232  C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
> Line 70   C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext
> httpContext) Line 87  C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext
> context) Line 123 C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext
> context) Line 75  C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext
> context) Line 75  C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext
> context) Line 75  C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext
> context) Line 74  C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext
> context) Line 50  C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext
> context) Line 95  C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext
> context) Line 65  C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext
> context) Line 80  C#
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware.Invoke(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext
> context) Line 51  C#
> Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.dll!Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.InvokeAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext
> context) Line 53  C#      [Resuming Async Method]
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>.AsyncStateMachineBox<Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.d__6>.ExecutionContextCallback(object
> s) Line 287   C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> state) Line 183   C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>.AsyncStateMachineBox<Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.d__6>.MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread
> threadPoolThread) Line 324    C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>.AsyncStateMachineBox<Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.d__6>.MoveNext()
> Line 302  C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.OutputWaitEtwEvents.AnonymousMethod__12_0(System.Action
> innerContinuation, System.Threading.Tasks.Task innerTask) Line 301    C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action
> action, bool allowInlining) Line 743  C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(object
> continuationObject) Line 3417 C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon>
> task, System.__Canon result) Line 446 C#      [Completed]
> Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.dll!Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.GetScriptTag(string
> requestId, bool isHttps, string hostUrl) Line 83  C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.d__7>.ExecutionContextCallback(object
> s) Line 287   C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> state) Line 183   C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.AsyncStateMachineBox<Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.d__7>.MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread
> threadPoolThread) Line 324    C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.d__7>.MoveNext()
> Line 302  C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.OutputWaitEtwEvents.AnonymousMethod__12_0(System.Action
> innerContinuation, System.Threading.Tasks.Task innerTask) Line 301    C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action
> action, bool allowInlining) Line 743  C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(object
> continuationObject) Line 3417 C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon>
> task, System.__Canon result) Line 446 C#      [Completed]
> System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsync.__Core|83_0(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage
> request, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption completionOption,
> System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, bool disposeCts,
> System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts,
> System.Threading.CancellationToken originalCancellationToken) Unknown
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<g__Core|83_0>d>.ExecutionContextCallback(object
> s) Line 287   C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> state) Line 183   C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<g__Core|83_0>d>.MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread
> threadPoolThread) Line 324    C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<g__Core|83_0>d>.MoveNext()
> Line 302  C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.OutputWaitEtwEvents.AnonymousMethod__12_0(System.Action
> innerContinuation, System.Threading.Tasks.Task innerTask) Line 301    C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action
> action, bool allowInlining) Line 743  C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(object
> continuationObject) Line 3417 C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon>
> task, System.__Canon result) Line 446 C#      [Completed]
> System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage
> request, bool async, System.Threading.CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    Unknown
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.d__4>.ExecutionContextCallback(object
> s) Line 287   C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> state) Line 183   C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.d__4>.MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread
> threadPoolThread) Line 324    C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.d__4>.MoveNext()
> Line 302  C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.OutputWaitEtwEvents.AnonymousMethod__12_0(System.Action
> innerContinuation, System.Threading.Tasks.Task innerTask) Line 301    C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action
> action, bool allowInlining) Line 743  C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(object
> continuationObject) Line 3417 C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon>
> task, System.__Canon result) Line 446 C#      [Completed]
> System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage
> request, bool async, System.Threading.CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    Unknown
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.d__10>.ExecutionContextCallback(object
> s) Line 287   C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> state) Line 183   C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.d__10>.MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread
> threadPoolThread) Line 324    C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.d__10>.MoveNext()
> Line 302  C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.OutputWaitEtwEvents.AnonymousMethod__12_0(System.Action
> innerContinuation, System.Threading.Tasks.Task innerTask) Line 301    C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action
> action, bool allowInlining) Line 743  C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(object
> continuationObject) Line 3417 C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon>
> task, System.__Canon result) Line 446 C#      [Completed]
> System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage
> request, bool async, bool doRequestAuth,
> System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Unknown
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.d__86>.ExecutionContextCallback(object
> s) Line 287   C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> state) Line 183   C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.d__86>.MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread
> threadPoolThread) Line 324    C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.d__86>.MoveNext()
> Line 302  C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.OutputWaitEtwEvents.AnonymousMethod__12_0(System.Action
> innerContinuation, System.Threading.Tasks.Task innerTask) Line 301    C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action
> action, bool allowInlining) Line 743  C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(object
> continuationObject) Line 3417 C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.__Canon>
> task, System.__Canon result) Line 446 C#      [Completed]
> System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage
> request, bool async, System.Threading.CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    Unknown
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.d__61>.ExecutionContextCallback(object
> s) Line 287   C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> state) Line 183   C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.d__61>.MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread
> threadPoolThread) Line 324    C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.d__61>.MoveNext()
> Line 302  C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.OutputWaitEtwEvents.AnonymousMethod__12_0(System.Action
> innerContinuation, System.Threading.Tasks.Task innerTask) Line 301    C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action
> action, bool allowInlining) Line 743  C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(object
> continuationObject) Line 3417 C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.TrySetResult(int
> result) Line 401  C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.SetExistingTaskResult(System.Threading.Tasks.Task
> task, int result) Line 446    C#      [Completed]
> System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.CheckUsabilityOnScavenge.__ReadAheadWithZeroByteReadAsync|44_0()   Unknown
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.<g__ReadAheadWithZeroByteReadAsync|44_0>d>.ExecutionContextCallback(object
> s) Line 287   C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext
> executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object
> state) Line 183   C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.<g__ReadAheadWithZeroByteReadAsync|44_0>d>.MoveNext(System.Threading.Thread
> threadPoolThread) Line 324    C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.AsyncStateMachineBox<System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.<g__ReadAheadWithZeroByteReadAsync|44_0>d>.MoveNext()
> Line 302  C#
> System.Net.Sockets.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.InvokeContinuation(System.Action
> continuation, object state, bool forceAsync, bool
> requiresExecutionContextFlow) Unknown
> System.Net.Sockets.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs
> _)    Unknown     System.Net.Sockets.dll!System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs..cctor.AnonymousMethod__176_0(uint
> errorCode, uint numBytes, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*
> nativeOverlapped) Unknown
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolTypedWorkItemQueue<System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.IOCompletionPoller.Event,
> System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.IOCompletionPoller.Callback>.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.Execute()
> Line 1143 C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
> Line 924  C#
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
> Line 121  C#      [Async Call Stack]      [Async]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.BrowserRefreshMiddleware.InvokeAsync(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext
> context)  Unknown     [Async]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context>(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IHttpApplication<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context>
> application)  Unknown     [Async]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context>(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IHttpApplication<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context>
> application)  Unknown     [Async]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.HttpConnection.ProcessRequestsAsync<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context>(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IHttpApplication<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.HostingApplication.Context>
> httpApplication)  Unknown     [Async]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Infrastructure.KestrelConnection<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionContext>.ExecuteAsync()    Unknown

Comment: That error is nothing to do with EF, it's an MVC error because you are passing the wrong model into the view

Comment: The exception is raised at that line and so the response does not get to the view.

Comment: Show full exception call stack.

Comment: And post the controller code. This has nothing to do with EF Core, it says that the *View* model contains invalid data. Most likely you forgot an `await` in an action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely when you changed this method to be `async` you neglected to change the code that calls to the method to `await` it before sending the result to the View. Since the return type of the method is now a `Task<List<Timetable>>` instead of a `List<Timetable>`, the view recognizes that it isn't an `IEnumerable<Timetable>` and throws an exception.

If the exception is appearing to come from this line of code, it may be due to the asynchronous task. Your method has already returned the Task, and the calling method has already invoked the View before this line of code actually finishes executing. But the stack trace doesn't appear to refer to this line of code anywhere: it clearly shows the Razor view throwing this exception when it validates the model type.